# Image appears stretched after loading Placeholder image via Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to use Glide to load a few images in a Listview. The image loads correctly if I don't use a placeholder while loading the image. However, when I attempt to set a placeholder, the image that I am loading from over the network appears stretched. This only occurs in instances where the placeholder image is used. If I were to leave the screen and return (so that no placeholder image is loaded) the image then appears correctly.

Here is my simple Glide implementation:

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.empty_logo)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: also add **CenterCrop** to your Glide implementation

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm answering pretty late, but this is how it helped me:

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.empty_logo).dontAnimate().into(imageView);
```

Use dontAnimate(), it worked for me. Hope it helped :)

Comment: Its worked for me. But the place holder image position is changing.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem where if the placeholder is smaller than the image being fetched, the image will be stretched when loaded onto the ImageView. I tried everything I could think of and the following worked perfectly for me:

I have the following attributes set on my ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

And used Glide in the following way:

```
Glide.with(myImageView.getContext())
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
            .into(myImageView);
```

The key things to note here is the **adjustViewBounds** attribute on the ImageView set to true and most importantly the **.override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)** - this will force Glide to use the original size of the image.

You can also specify the size in pixels in **.override()** but make sure to then specify the correct ScaleType for your ImageView otherwise it will also stretch the image.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that, you have given both Imageview widht and height as Wrap_content. 
So whenever Glide load Images some Images may be larger in size, so it's streteched.

Try this out.

```
<ImageView
android:width="match_parent"
android:height="50dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```